Ratio of expectations of hitting times to the same boundary by Brownian Motions with different drifts
Consider two processes on a finite time interval $[0, T]$:
$$
X_1(t) = -x + at + W(t),
$$
$$
X_2(t) = -x - at + W(t),
$$
where $x > 0$ is some starting position, and $W(\cdot)$ is a standard Brownian motion.
Consider also some boundary function $b: [0, T] \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $b(0) = 0$ and the boundary is sufficiently nice to make sense of the following question, but not too nice, i.e., not Lipschitz-continuous.
Now let $\tau_i, i = 1, 2$ be hitting times of the above processes $X_i$ to the boundary $b(\cdot)$, i.e., define
$$
\tau_i = \inf \{t \ge 0: X_i(t) \ge b(t) \} \wedge T, \quad i = 1, 2.
$$
I now want to compare the expectations of these hitting times. It is clear that, since $X_1 \ge X_2$, we have $\tau_1 \le \tau_2$. I am curious whether we have a bound
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}_x[\tau_2]}{\mathbb{E}_x[\tau_1]} < C, \quad (1)
$$
for some finite constant $0 \le C < \infty$ which is independent of $x$. In other words, I want to show that for all small $x$ there exists a universal constant $C < \infty$ such that (1) holds.
One way to approach this problem is to express both expectations via the expectation of a hitting time of a simple Brownian motion under corresponding Girsanov's measures, but I was not able to get much insight from this representation. Nor was I able to split the interval into $n$ small parts and compare gitting times over these subintervals. Maybe, I am missing something obvious.
Any help/advice/reference would be greatly appreciated!
